# Não consigo executar uma procedure no Firebird

Tags: firebird, procedure

Boa tarde pessoal. Preciso inserir um registro no banco de dados mas sem duplicações. Tentei isso:

```
create procedure My_Proc
as begin

if(not exists(select * from alunos where nome = 'Mateus')) then

insert into Alunos (Matricula, Nome, Idade, OBS) 
values (6, 'Mateus', 5, 'É terrível');

end
```

Não reconhece o ';' no final do comando insert. Se eu tirar o ';', não reconhece o END.
Alguém sabe o que está faltando ?

Estou usando o Flaming Robin.

OBS: Se eu usar o execute block, os mesmos erros acontecem.

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou bastante, só que no lugar do create procedure eu usei um execute block.

Agora eu entendi porque tem sintaxes que funcionam no Flame Robin e não funcionam nos meu projetos e vice versa.
Vlw filhão !

Answer (score 1):

Talvez o uso do SET TERM ([Instruções set term)](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq78/) solucione seu problema.

```
create procedure My_Proc
 as begin


 SET TERM  ^;

 if(not exists(select * from alunos where nome = 'Mateus')) then

 insert into Alunos (Matricula, Nome, Idade, OBS) 
 values (6, 'Mateus', 5, 'É terrível');

 end ^
```